# Looking for info on a very heavy snow that fell in Airdrie AB in May of about 1992

Tags: snow

I have been looking on the internet and can't find the title subject. Three friends and I spent 2 days snowed in a strangers house in Airdrie AB during May , about 1992. We are talking about close to a meter of snow; Calgary and Edmonton got much less snow. I had been in a gas plant north of Airdrie and was heading back to Calgary . Heavy snow, I stopped the rental car to pick up a stranded couple ( since it was May many locals had removed snow tires).  I went a mile and drifted off the highway in the whiteout. Two guys behind me ( with whom I had worked ) stopped in their pickup with chains , essentially no other cars were moving.  We left the highway at Airdrie to take the stranded couple home . The couple said " you can't go further stay with us", so we did. Wood stove heat and a lot of venison ( power was off). Roads were not open for two days. I was looking for the official snow fall and possibly other info.

Comment: This question is not concise and to the point. You need to state exactly which snowstorm, what makes it exceptional and exactly what you want to know about it. A more recent and more exceptional weather event would make a better subject.

Comment: Checked environment Canada's historical weather website and did not find anything unusual for the dates you mention.  Tighter date range would help

Comment: [Twenty-Five Years Later: The snowstorm that changed their lives](https://www.airdrietoday.com/entertainment-news/twenty-five-years-later-the-snowstorm-that-changed-their-lives-1403226) ? [May blizzard blankets Calgary region](https://www.theglobeandmail.com/news/national/may-blizzard-blankets-calgary-region/article25296474/) ? I remember there were people with tickets to a big game watching it on a portable TV running off a car battery. Snow clearing was slowed because they had to probe the drifts for cars.

Comment: If you go here: https://calgary.weatherstats.ca/metrics/snow.html you can quickly scroll through different years to see the most snow in May.  Looks like 1986 and 1997 had nearly 30 cm of snow in May.  1992 was much less than that with closer to 10 cm.  Here is a list of snowiest days which has those May records: https://www.currentresults.com/Yearly-Weather/Canada/AB/Calgary/extreme-annual-calgary-snowfall.php

Comment: Interesting that there are no snow records for 1992 ,1993 in the "current.....". Also it seems Airdrie is not big enough to have weather records. As I say , the heavy snow did not reach Calgary.